# Modify dictionary to add new keys and values to existing entries

Tags: python, dictionary

here is me again asking for help in order to keep learning Python. Thanks in advance to everyone who takes the time to contribute here.

So, let's say I have this dictionary:

```
{
    "Pres": "John",
    "King": "Henri"
}
```

And what I want is to add a "sub dictionary" to each entry, getting an output like this

```
{
  "Pres": {
    "Name": "John",
    "link": "example.com"
  },
  "King": {
    "Name": "Henri",
    "link": "example2.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are the URLs coming from?

Comment: Why did the key `Pres` change to `Pres.` (with an added `.`)?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: mozway: I'll get the URLs from a api reponse. For this example, let's say we have them as a list in a variable urls = ["example.com", "example2.com"]

Barmar: it was a typo. I'll update my message.

PCM: Nothing so far as I don't know where to start :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
d = {
    "Pres": "John",
    "King": "Henri"
}

for key in d:
    d[key] = {
        'Name': d[key],
        'link': 'dummyLink'
    }

print(d)
```

You can replace dummy link by something else

Comment: Thank you , it works in the example. I'll try now to integrate in my real project :)

Comment: @arkanjie Anytime pal, I am glad it worked :)

Comment: a name like `_dict` looks a bit awkward - suggest some other name, like `d` for ex.

Comment: also, there's no need to use a `tempDict` at all - try it out!

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thanks for your suggestion, will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the old dict containing the names and a list of urls and create new dictionaries like this:

```py
names_dict = {
    "Pres": "John",
    "King": "Henri",
}
urls = ["example.com", "example2.com"]
new_dict = {}

for (key, name), url in zip(names_dict.items(), urls):
    new_dict[key] = {"Name": name, "link": url}

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It's great to see another alternative so I can study both :)